# Why is it not possible to send a message to another user from another network knowing his ip address?

Tags: unix, server, tcp, ip

Hey guys sorry for my stupid question but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to find a unix application to send a message to my friend by his IP address, but I didn't succeed.

If the remote server can do it, why can't I.

Or is it really not an interesting task, and no one has done it?.

Comment: *"If the remote server can do it, why can't I."* - can it?  It is unclear here what remote server you are talking about, but commonly the server does not send the message to a specific IP, but instead a user contacts the server and gets the message as response. An internal user can contact an external server, so this works. But an internal user cannot contact another internal user inside another network because of private IP addresses, NAT, firewalls ...

Comment: Are you trying to use something like 4.3 BSD talk(1)?  Or email?  Or what?  What OS?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks, I already understood that the server does not send messages on its own and that there are such concepts as restapi and websocket and most likely others ... I don’t know about NAT and firewall. Thanks.